# How to trigger notifications from my backend using Firebase?

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing push notifications for my Ionic app.
I have a notification service in which I have:

```
// Get permission from the user
  async getToken() {
    let token;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      token = await this.firebase.getToken();
    }
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      await this.firebase.grantPermission();
      token = await this.firebase.getToken();
      // await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
    }
    console.log('Saving token ' + token + ' to Firebase and Askme');
    return this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
  }


  // Save the token
  private saveTokenToFirestore(token: string){
    if(!token){
      return;
    }
      const devicesRef = this.firestore.collection('devices');
      if (this.licenseService.currentLicense) {
          this.configService.getStoredUsername(this.licenseService.currentLicense.referenceURL).then((username: string) => {
            const docData = {
                token,
                userId: username,
            };
            return  devicesRef.doc(token).set(docData);
          });
      }
  }

  // Listen to incoming FCM messages
  onNotifications() {
    return this.firebase.onMessageReceived();
  }
```

And in my app.component:

```
// Get a token
      this.notservice.getToken();

      this.notservice.onNotifications().pipe(
        tap(async msg => {
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: msg.body,
          duration: 5000
          });
          toast.present();
        })
      )
    .subscribe();
      });
```

I'm currently getting push notifications from Firebase console, but I'd like to connect Firebase to my app server. I have a method that returns messages and it's this:

```
onMessage:(msg) => {
            this.receiveMessage(msg);
```

How can I link this method to my Firebase configuration in order to see this "msg" as a push notification?
I practically need to trigger notifications from my backend.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Notification through Firebase using Firebase Cloud Functions:

Below is an example in NodeJs :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.sendPush = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  const categoryId = request.query.categoryId;

  const topicName = 'status_all';
  const payload = {
    data : {
      sound: "default",
      categoryId: categoryId
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topicName,payload).then(function(res){
    response.send('Success: ' + res);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    response.send('Error: ' + err);
  });
});
```

When you deploy this, it will give you an endpoint. You can call this endpoint from backend to fire the notification or you can write a cron on your backend server which will fire this at particular interval.

---

If you **only need to test** your notification implementation by firing a notification through backend, you can follow this approach.
https://apoorv487.medium.com/testing-fcm-push-notification-through-postman-terminal-part-1-5c2df94e6c8d

Comment: your answer does not address the question at all

Comment: @Llama I explained, how to send notifications using Firebase Cloud functions, which is a backend. The user can call this from his server which is the intent I believe.

Comment: @Llama From the question as mentioned "I practically need to trigger notifications from my backend",  I understood this only. Triggers like Database trigger etc is not mentioned there. Could you help me out in understanding, if I miss anything?